# How To pass a Value in Html webview url?

Tags: android, webview

i want to load html url in webview from raw folder it working fine

```
url = "file:///android_res/raw/a1.html";


        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

But i want pass a value in url like this

```
String s = "1";
url = "file:///android_res/raw/a"+s+".html";
```

but its not working please help how can i achieve this.

Comment: What is not working? Can you give more information?

Comment: Log your url string and post the log here

Comment: solved this was my little mistake

Answer (score 0):

This is done in the same way on `android` as in `Java SE`.

Put your complete `URL` inside `URLEncoder`

```
try {
    String url = "http://www.example.com/?id=123&art=abc";
    String encodedurl = URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8");

    Log.d("TEST", encodedurl);
    } 
 catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first, u can not insure `url = "file:///android_res/raw/a"+s+".html";` is a useful file path. so, this method can not work as you planed.

you can use 
   webview.loadUrl("javascript:xxxx");
 to pass a parameter to html .

or use `url = "file:///android_res/raw/a.html?action=go";`